# AbstractPropertySection.refresh() is being called twice

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

When I select an edit part in gef editor that is hooked up to Properties View, Section page's refresh method is being called twice. I debugged the calls and see that it's being called first time from setInput and second from setSelection on the Viewer. Is this normal behavior, or am I doing something in setting up the sections?

[Screenshot of the calls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TtnKs.png)

Comment: Did you set some "preserveSelection"-Flag in the viewer? Its kinda weird that the "setInput" call is followed by setSelection, which makes the 2nd setSelection call superfluous, if its the same selection.

Comment: No I did not. I am not even using viewer directly, only through the extension point.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround for this I decided to employ time calculation to call refresh only if time difference between two calls into refresh() is more than 60 milliseconds.

```
   if(timestamp == 0){
        timestamp = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MILLISECOND);
    }
    else{
        long newTimeStamp = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MILLISECOND);
        long diff = newTimeStamp - timestamp;

        if(diff < 60){
            timestamp = 0;
            return;
        }
        else{
            timestamp = newTimeStamp;
        }
    }
```